# What is the critical difference between 'Number.parseInt()', 'Number.parseFloat()', 'Number()' or '+'?

Tags: javascript, function, methods, numbers

The basic question here is how do I know when to use and

what is the critical difference between each of them:

- The `Number.parseInt` method (or just `parseInt`),
- `Number.parseFloat` method (or just `parseFloat`),
- `Number()` function (or class?),
- and the `+` operator

for converting JavaScript values (mostly `String`'s) to numbers.

Especially since all of them give similar values and can convert `String` to its `Number` representation:

```
Number.parseInt("2")   // returns 2
Number.parseFloat("2") // returns 2
Number("2")            // returns 2
+"2"                   // returns 2

/* Plus a few more methods... */
eval("2")              // returns 2
JSON.parse("2")        // returns 2
```

Comment: `Number.parseInt("2.1") === 2` whereas `Number.parseFloat("2.1") === 2.1`

Comment: Yea, that's all well and good but what about the others: `Number` and the `+` operator?

Would I be wrong doing `+"2.5"` over `parseFloat("2.5")`?

Comment: Well "2.5"+"2.5" returns "2.52.5". So I would be careful with that.

Comment: True, true.

Although for basic conversations from `String` to `Number` in functions the `+` operator would be useful.

    `const convertStringToNumber(data) => { return +data }`

Comment: Use functions based on what they are primarily intended for. `Number.parse*` is primarily intended convert a string into a number. `eval()`evaluates an expression - most people will tell you to avoid this function. `JSON.parse()` is primarily used to convert a JSON string into a Javascript value or object. Even if `+` operator achieves your goal, it is not primarily used to convert Strings into number but to sum two numbers. I didn't even know you can do that.

Comment: Too broad, depends on use case, precision wanted, known input type and other variables

Comment: I just edited the question...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- `Number.parseInt` method (or just `parseInt`)

  - Ignores leading and trailing whitespace
  - Parses a leading number to an integer (not a floating point number)
  - Ignores invalid trailing data
  - Lets you set the base to use when interpreting the number
  - Will interpret text starting with `0x` as hexadecimal, if another base was not provided
  - Returns `NaN` if the value could not be successfully parsed to an integer
- `Number.parseFloat` method (or just `parseFloat`)

  - Similar to `parseInt`, except that it allows for a decimal part to be interpreted
  - Only parses to base-10
- `Number()` function (or class?)

  - Similar to `parseFloat`, but does not allow trailing text
  - Will return `0` for an empty string or a string that only contains whitespace
  - It's not a class; when called without `new`, it returns a primitive number
- the `+` operator

  - Basically the same as `Number()`, but in operator form.
- `eval()`

  - Interprets and executes the given input as a JavaScript program.
  - Given the string `"2"`, it will be interpreted as a numeric literal, and return that value since it's the result of the last expression in the program
  - Throws an error if the input was not a valid program.
- `JSON.parse()`

  - Parses the textual data as JSON-serialized data.
  - If the data is valid, it creates the JavaScript objects/primitives that are represented by the data, and returns them.
  - If the data is invalid, it throws an error.
  - Given the string `"2"`, it will be interpreted as a numeric literal, and return the value that was successfully parsed out of it according to the parsing requirements of JSON.

So you decide which is appropriate to use based on their capabilities.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be more careful with how I interpret JavaScript values and numbers in my code now.

Answer (score 4):

`Number.parseInt()` calls the global function `parseInt()` in the background, same with `Number.parseFloat()` see: [Number.parseInt ECMA](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-number.parseint) and [Number.parseFloat ECMA](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-number.parsefloat)

The calls `Number("2")` and `"+2"` is identical in the background, they both call [ToNumber](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-tonumber) see: [Number](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-number-constructor) and [Unary + Operator](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-unary-plus-operator)

When you know what types you are working with, or want a guaranteed type back, use `parseFloat` and `parseInt`, otherwise it tends to be easier to only use `Number()` as it will work within all your calculations, many people choose to use the unary + operator because they find it more pleasing to read/type, but that is only based on preference as it is identical to `Number()`.

Also, when you using `parseInt()`, you can specify a radix, which is useful in certain applications where you want to work in different number systems, which you cannot do with `Number()`

If the ECMA standard references does not explain the details for you enough, I will add a summary for you.